# How do I scroll down the browser using Browser library of robot framework?

Tags: browser, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I am working on automation using Browser library of Robot Framework. I have to scroll down the browser to check the links. I am using VSCODE, used python to install. I checked documentation:https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html#Scroll%20To
But I dont understand. I see people using javascript but I dont think my company uses javascript(in with Selenium) in this case.

I tried several keywords of the library but it keeps giving error. I was expecting it to scroll down the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code and it works:

1. To scroll till some point:

Scroll By            ${None}           300         0           smooth

There are four arguments to Scroll By keyword:
i. Selector  that you can set as ${None}
ii. 300 - for vertical scrolling
iii. 0 - for horizontal scrolling (no scrolling in this case)
iv. smooth - smooth or direct scroll behavior

2. To scroll completely down:

   Scroll To        ${None}             bottom       left        auto

There are four arguments to Scroll To keyword:
i. Selector  that you can set as ${None}
ii. bottom - for vertical scrolling
iii. left - for horizontal scrolling
iv. auto - direct or smooth scroll behavior

Hope this works for you. Also please share the error that you are getting in case it still doesn't work.